# Can I get order details from the PayPal API using the token in the redirect URL?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have a PayPal subscription set up on a Wordpress site. After the payment, the user is redirected back to `domain.com/?token=ABCDABCDABCD`

Can I use the `token` parameter in the URL to get the order/transaction info from the PayPal API? The documentation doesn't seem to help.

The only `token` that I can find in the docs is the authentication token, so I'm not sure what this one is supposed to be. I was under the impression that the return URL should have the subscription ID, but that looks like `I-ABCDEFGH` and it's not there even though the subscription is created successfully on PayPal.

Comment: No, 
you also need Client_id and Secret or of course a valid auth token

Comment: @BadPussycat I have the client_id and secret. It's my own account. But I can't find how I can use the token to fetch the payment/subscription details.

Comment: Never worked with Subscriptions myself but according to the docu you need this request
`curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"`
(of course not the sandbox url)
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get

Comment: does this help? Or you need more detailed answer?

Comment: @BadPussycat That request uses the subscription ID. This is a different thing from the token. It always begins with "I-" while the token is just a random string.

Comment: ok sorry then I have no idea. I think you should look in the logs to find out what token this is. (maybe  you find out what subscription id is assigned to that token)

Comment: I guess this is the payment_id

Comment: So maybe you it's worth tying the payment api. maybe in the response is a hint to what subcription the payment belongs. Just a wild guess ;-)

Comment: Look here, I think is the parameter for this API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts-get-response. If you check the response, you should receive the entire list of items

Comment: @MarcoMassetti Those are payouts...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the return url to your return url plus a userId param, and if you save the orderId in the userDoc in your remote db you can access thought this.

For example with firebase I create the order, save the orderId in the user document, then return the url to customer pay with

```
"return_url": `yourApp/onPaymentComplete?userId=${userId}`
```

Then access to the userId by the request.query and take the orderId in the userId doc and with this orderId you can call to the get method  ***show order details***

i hope it helps